# Flutter: how to clip text from top instead of bottom when changing height of Container?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the below setup:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Wrap(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              height: 100,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 30,
              child: Text(
                'Workout name',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 50,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.amber),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Notice the `height: 30` defined in the Container which contains the `Text`.

It looks like this:

[image]

Currently, the text is being clipped from the bottom because of the `height: 30` defined in the parent `Container`. I want it to clip the text from the top instead. How can I do that?

So instead of the top of `Workout name` being visible, I want the bottom to be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Are you looking for this

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Wrap(
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          height: 100,
        ),
        Container(
          height: 30,
          child: Stack(
            // overflow: Overflow.clip,
            children: [
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                child: Text(
                  'Workout name',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 50, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, backgroundColor: Colors.amber),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately there is no way to clip from top. Because the parent's height of text is clearly 30. If you want to achieve this you can use Stack widget instead which will have two children. A Text at first, and above it a container with height of 30 and white color.

It would look like this:

```
Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Wrap(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            height: 100,
          ),
          Stack(
            children: [
              Text(
                'Workout name',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 50,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.amber),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 30,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  )
```